# ERROR: Failed to decipher auth data. reason: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, git

I am getting this error:

> Failed to decipher auth data. reason: Unsupported state or unable to
>   authenticate data.

Anytime I try to run a sfdx force:auth, force:org:display, force:org:open command. I am running these commands from my gitlab ci yaml file for Gitlab to Salesforce CI/CD pipeline. Other sfdx commands work, like sfdx --version..etc. The build gives me the error above I am not sure why.

Comment: I had this error when I was trying to list using force:org:list --all. I resorted to force:auth:web:login for each of the orgs that was still important to me and that fixed it. Perhaps the auth token expired and needed to be regenerated. However, you get this when you do a force:auth as well, so I'm not sure. I deleted the unused orgs from the ~/.sfdx directory so they won't show up in my force:org:list anymore. Hope it helps.